# Conditional SQL query for Unique Record in Talend

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, unique, talend

[image]
**This is the data in my Oracle database.**

I have a requirement for Data load from attached excel file. 
 The attached file has data for Unit Number and its type(D_NUMBER) and its value(R_Value).

The requirement is as follows :

1)       For every Unit Number I need to have 1 record

2)       In case there are multiple records for a Unit Serial Number the logic to be used is :
- Consider record which has D_NUMBER starting with F
-  If we have multiple records with D_NUMBER starting with F , we need to consider Max D_NUMBER from the set.
-  Incase a Unit number doesn’t have  D_NUMBER starting with F , then we need to consider D_NUMBER starting with G or E
- Incase a Unit number does have  D_NUMBER starting with F or G , then we need to consider D_NUMBER starting with G

**This is the desired output :** 
[image]

**How do I design a Talend Job to meet the requirements or build a SQL query to use it in talend ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` analytic function to rank your results. They both use `ORDER BY` clause for that. And in `ORDER BY` you can use `DECODE` or `CASE` to conditionally order rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT UNIT_NUMBER,
         D_NUMBER,
         R_VALUE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UNIT_NUMBER
                           ORDER BY DECODE(SUBSTR(D_NUMBER, 1, 1),
                                           'F', 1,
                                           'G', 2,
                                           'E', 3,
                                                4),
                                    D_NUMBER DESC)  N_ROW
   FROM   <your_table_name>)
WHERE N_ROW = 1
```

Also it's not clear if you need max `D_NUMBER` string or max numeric value. In the example I just put `D_NUMBER` in `ORDER BY`. If you need its numeric value, you can extract digits from the string using regex and cast to number.

```
TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(D_NUMBER, '\d+'))
```

Comment: If the value of D_NUMBER is F139 and F250A then I need F250A. Or if it is F139 and F250 then I need F250.

Comment: Well I assumed that answering the question. `ORDER BY` clause from the example should work then.

Comment: Also, I would like to eliminate the null values(R_Value) for the duplicates(D_NUMBER) ? where can I add this ? Will this query work in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Add something like `DECODE(R_VALUE, NULL, 1, 2) DESC` at the beginning of `ORDER BY` clause so that rows with null values get larger `N_ROW` and get filtered if there are rows with not-null values. For PostgreSQL you'll need `CASE` instead of `DECODE` as there is no support for it in PostgreSQL.